# jpanel with image in background

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I have a simple doubt, I need to replace this:

```
panel[1].setBackground(Color.red);
```

For an image, but I want to avoid a new `jlabel` for image, because I tested and I have another label inside this panel that is pushed to below

Answer (score 1):

[Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) shows two approaches. One involves custom painting, the other involves using a JLabel. The approach you use will be based on your requirement. The custom painting is more flexible but a little more complicated.

Comment: Great example, look at the paintComponent function in BackgroundPanel.java

Comment: i have seen the example before, and honestly I was in the same